# How to drop a row in pandas dataframe if there is only word in a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

How do we drop an entire row on pandas dataframe if there is an item in a column that only has one word

Example:

```
'the cat likes mice',
'the dog likes the cat',
'dog'
```

Return

```
'the cat likes mice',
'the dog likes the cat'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the `pd.Series.str.contains` method to look for spaces:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'items': ['the cat likes mice',
                             'the dog likes the cat',
                             'dog']})

df = df[df['items'].str.contains(' ')]
```